# How do I create two different button groups

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, buttongroup

I am creating two button groups. whenever I click a button from second button group, already selected button from 1st group is getting deselected. i am able to select only one button both group. i want to select one button from each group.

```
<li class="col-md-12 panel-select">
     <div class="col-md-2">Subject</div>
     <div class="col-md-9" id="">
           <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="..."><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">English</button></div>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="..."><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Geography</button></div>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="..."><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">History</button></div>        
       </div>              
   </li>
   <li class="col-md-12 panel-select">
        <div class="col-md-2">Class</div>
       <div class="col-md-9" id="">
         <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="..."><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">I</button></div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="..."><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">II</button></div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="..."><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">III</button></div>
   </div>
</li>`
```

Comment: Could you make it clear ? What i got from above are when user click English (Subject) then automatically either of Class (I, II or III) get selected, is that right ?

Comment: Ridoan, User wants to select one button from each of the group. For example, User wants to click English from subject and II from Class.. When he clicks Class II, English is getting deselected. User can able to select one button from all... Hope this clarifies..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step by step to get this done :

1. Add a class to a selected button that user just clicked
     `$(this).addClass("selected");`
2. Create custom css for the selected button (which we named selected).
     `.selected {
     background-color: #A8A8A8;
     color: #FFFFFF;
   }`
3. Get the id of button's parent that was selected.
     `group = $(this).parent().attr('id');`
4. Get all the child elements of the button's parent that was selected. Then store these to variable which named childClasses.
     `childClasses = $("#" + group).children();`
5. Check if there were previous button have selected in the same group button. If any, just remove 'selected' class from those elements.

   `for(var i = 0; i < childClasses.length; i++){
       if(this.textContent != childClasses[i].textContent){
           $("#" + childClasses[i].id).removeClass("selected");
       }
   }`

> You could also learn from the source code i've provided below. I hope this helps you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-default").click(function() {

    var childClasses, group;

    // add class "selected" to a clicked button
    $(this).addClass("selected");

    // get the parent's id of button element 
    group = $(this).parent().attr('id');

    // store all element of selected group 
    childClasses = $("#" + group).children();

    // remove previous selected button when user select a new button in the same group button
    for (var i = 0; i < childClasses.length; i++) {
      if (this.textContent != childClasses[i].textContent) {
        $("#" + childClasses[i].id).removeClass("selected");
      }
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Example</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <style type="text/css">
    .selected {
      background-color: #A8A8A8;
      color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    
    .row {
      padding: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-4">Subject</div>
      <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
        <div class="btn-group" id="group1" role="group" aria-label="...">
          <button type="button" id="subject1" class="button1 btn btn-default">English</button>
          <button type="button" id="subject2" class="button1 btn btn-default">Geography</button>
          <button type="button" id="subject3" class="button1 btn btn-default">History</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-4">Class</div>
      <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
        <div class="btn-group" id="group2" role="group" aria-label="...">
          <button type="button" id="class1" class="button2 btn btn-default">I</button>
          <button type="button" id="class2" class="button2 btn btn-default">II</button>
          <button type="button" id="class3" class="button2 btn btn-default">III</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Ridoan, When I click a button from second group, first group selection is removed... the issue still ramains..

Comment: @passionFinder .. i've fixed it. Just check it out.